# Cancel Task.Delay(TimeSpan) if condition is met prior to timespan

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

I have below code which waits for 300 ms and then verify the condition i.e. isMatch is True.

```
await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300));

if (isMatch)
{
//do something
isMatch = false;
}
else{

}
```

How can I avoid this 300 ms constant wait when isMatch variable value is True before 300 ms time is over on in other words my code should execute based on the the any of the event occurs first i.e. either isMatch value is true or 300 ms are over.

App has a timer which runs after every 100 ms which is responsible for setting the value of isMatch as True.

Comment: How does `isMatch` get set? We can't tell you how you can stop waiting early if `isMatch` is set unless you show us how you set it.

Comment: App has a timer which runs after every 100 ms which is responsible for setting this value.

Comment: Show don't tell, edit your question and include the code showing the timer

Answer (score 3):

You cancel a `Task.Delay` by passing a `CancellationToken` into it.

So, whenever your code sets `isMatch` to `true`, also have it call `CancellationTokenSource.Cancel`.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I will try this approach.